# Match list of patterns in order in a file using awk

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I'd like to match a list of newline-separated regular expressions against another file, in order (that is, regex1 must be matched before matching regex2), and succeed iff all regular expressions are matched. This needs to be done in awk because I don't have convenient access to python and perl on said platform.

So file1 will contain

```
address 0x[0-9]*
disk [a-zA-Z]:\\
```

And file2 will contain:

```
asm
address 0xfae2222
jubkj
disk C:\
aaa
```

In this case, I want the script to succeed.

I know it's possible to perform a certain action when matching a pattern, eg `'/pattern/{ print $0 }'`, but I don't think there's a way to indicate the relationship between two patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk

```
 awk 'NR==FNR&&NF{a[++x]=$0;next}
      FNR==1{current=1}
      $0~a[current]{current<x&&current++||success=1}
      END{if(success)print "success";else print "fail"}' file1 file2
```

Comment: This might verify that all patterns from file1 are somewhere in file2, but OP requires (if I understand correctly) that the patterns are found within file2 in the same order that they occur in file1.

Comment: @jas Oh yeah, didin't see that, gimme a minute!

Comment: Neat!, works for me, hopefully for the asker as well. (Looks like you lost the `file1` `file2` inputs during the edit.)

Comment: Is it possible to get the success and failure as the program's errorlevel/return value?

Comment: @nitzanms change print to exit and then the return code you want e.g `if(success)exit 0;else exit 10`

Comment: Sigh, Linux's awk returns a (correct) success, but busybox's awk fails on the same input. I'm accepting your answer because while I don't have the awk chops to verify your answer I did run it on some sample inputs and it works. If you have some suggestion regarding why busybox's awk fails I'd be happy to hear.

Comment: @nitzanms whats the result of `awk --version` ?

Comment: It is an unrecognized argument. So is -v, sadly. Busybox's version is 1.21.1

Comment: @nitzanms how does it fail ?

Comment: @123 It prints out "fail"

Comment: @nitzanms i have absolutely no idea sorry.